# How do the Batman Cuffs work in Batman Fluxx?

Tags: fluxx

The Batman Cuffs card says you can hide a Creeper.

1. Does this mean that Creeper is now under your control?
2. Can you hide someone else's Creeper?
3. What happens when you choose to unhide it? Is it yours or your opponents'?

Unclear still on how the Batcuffs work based on these two official sources:

- [Q: How exactly do the Batman Cuffs work?](http://faq.looneylabs.com/fluxx-games/batman-fluxx#758) (Batman™ Fluxx FAQ),
- http://looneylabs.ning.com/forum/topics/rules-question-batman-cuffs (dead link, verified on 29.12.2020).

Answer (score 1):

The FAQ already answers part of your question:

> Q: How exactly do the Batman Cuffs work?
>
> A: Yes, the wording on that Keeper is a bit vague. The intention is
>   that you can hide one Creeper under the card on your turn. You can
>   reveal it at any time, but the hiding can only be done on your turn.
>   We will be updating the wording on subsequent print runs to make that
>   clear.

Remains the question if you can hide someone else's creeper.

We can'be sure what the intention is on this one. But based on several Fluxx set's I own, I assume you can't. There are a few cards that work on other player's creepers and these are spelled out. So it is not likely that you can use these for creepers you don't control.

Comment: Cuffing a Creeper then leads only to its inability to be used further until uncuffed correct? Say someone removes the cuffs Keeper, then what happens to the Creeper?

Comment: What exactly does hiding a creeper mean? Does it still count towards goals? Does it still stop people from winning?

Comment: Hiding a creeper would mean it can't be counted towards goals. But it would also hide the Creeper from Creeper effects as well. Once "uncuffed" the creeper would just be revealed again.